# Microsoft Intellipoint Mouse & control panel (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, mouse, control-panel, mouse-buttons, intellimouse

When at work (with laptop), I have a Microsoft Intellipoint mouse. The driver for this mouse replaces the default "Buttons" panel in the mouse control panel, which means that if I either remote desktop in, or use another mouse (out and about, undocked, and using portable mouse), access to the "Buttons" panel is disabled.

Why is this a problem? I'm left handed, and run with the mouse buttons reversed: obviously, this gets annoying when I'm away as Windows reverts back to standard mouse defaults - i.e., right-handed.

Short of uninstalling the MS mouse driver and forcing it to use the standard driver, is there anyway anyone's aware of to either get the normal "buttons" to display, or some other hack to swap the buttons, that works both with remote desktops and with non-MS mice plugged in (using machine directly).

I'm using Windows 7, but suspect this is a generic mouse driver problem rather than a Windows 7 problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the Intellipoint driver was removed. This may lose me some functionality however it's given me the functionality I want rather than the functionality Microsoft think I need :-)